# Issue in Reusable workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, reusable-workflow

I have created a reusable workflow, and attached a list to it. Once the workflow is published, I have added the workflow for two content types in particular library.

When I am creating a document set, the permissions are not getting unique permissions. I don't know where the issue is.

Please help onto this.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the reusable workflow?

Which actions are added into the reusable workflow?

Did you create the reusable workflow 2010 or workflow 2013?

Which two content types did you add the workflow for?

Did you change the item permission in the reusable workflow?